# Is it proper to edit an answer with updated information?

Tags: discussion, edits

The StackOverflow question: [How do you do a SQL style 'IN' statement in LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework) if Contains isn't supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328600/210709)

I am not the author of the accepted answer so I didn't want to update without feeling it was the right thing to do. I simply commented that information on the subject has been updated.

Is it acceptable to edit an answer with new/updated information? Or should we just leave a comment? Is a comment enough to maintain relevance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the answer is just slightly different, an edit shouldn't hurt, but you may want to explicitly note that there was a change due to time. Keeps people off your toes if they do try to bite.

If the answer is completely different now, though, why not just post a new answer of your own? An accepted answer that becomes invalid over time is certainly fine to one-up with a better answer. You may even score yourself a Necromancer badge for the act.

Comment: I don't think I really want to take anything away from the original author who wrote, at that time, a perfectly acceptable answer. :)

Comment: you could have just edited my answer, I said the same thing!

Comment: @lAbstract It's up to you whether you consider it "robbing" the acceptance or not. But it's not that much different than [answering a question which had formerly accepted a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847144/adding-a-cloned-spview-to-a-list/2273261#2273261).

Comment: @Chester If this answer is any indication, I'm not exactly fond of significantly changing someone else's answer when it's also perfectly valid to post a separate answer due to the difference of content within.

Answer (score 4):

Of course! One of the best features of this system is the ability to keep answers current and keep the communities content as accurate as possible...

Or better said...

### YOU BETCHA!